# Fineuploader uploading directly to Azure Blob Storage - get file uri within Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, fine-uploader

I am uploading files via fineuploader directly to Azure Blob Storage and I want to know if I can access file URI (on Azure Blob Storage) once file is uploaded?

I understand that I can call API where fineuploader provides all kinds of information which is described in http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/fix_thumbnail-performance/endpoint_handlers/azure.html#optional-server-side-tasks but I wonder if there is some possibility to access this information (file uri etc) in javascript callback - without sending it to any API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this one. I am using internal API of fineuploader - I didn't find it documented anywhere.

In `complete` event I am calling this:

```
var blobName = $(this).fineUploaderAzure("getBlobName", id);
```

Edit:
As Ray mentioned in comment below this feature is documented in [official documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods-azure.html#getBlobName)

Comment: That is documented at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods-azure.html#getBlobName

Comment: I didn't find it but I don't know why since it is in main documentation. Thanks for useful information

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your definition of "API" is. I assume you mean that you simply don't want to make extra calls to the server.

You can return any information needed by your client-side code your response to Fine Uploader's upload success POST. The parameters will be made available to your onComplete callback handler.

There are also a [large number of API methods](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html) that may be of use, including one to retrieve the file name.